# Extract GTA V rpf file

Tags: c#, rage-engine

I'm trying to make a GTA V car adder but I do not know how to extract the `.rpf` file using c#, I tried ionic but of course, it reported that it was not a zip file and it couldn't extract it!

Does anyone know how I can extract these `.rpf` files with C#?

An example rpf file can be found here: [Common.rpf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxO67ahQXmync2ZDRVhXQU56OWs/view?usp=sharing)

And this is the code I've tried:

```
this.Text = "Unpacking...";
try
{
    string zipToUnpack = openFileDialog1.FileName; // = "Common.rpf" in this case
    string unpackDirectory = "Unpacked\\" + strFileName;
    using (ZipFile zip1 = ZipFile.Read(zipToUnpack))
    {
        // here, we extract every entry, but we could extract conditionally
        // based on entry name, size, date, checkbox status, etc.  
        foreach (ZipEntry zipen in zip1)
        {
            zipen.Extract(unpackDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Extraction Failed! " + exc.ToString());
}
```

The Output of said code is "Cannot read that as a zip file, bad signature".

Comment: Can you link to a very small example rpf file and post code you've tried so we can see better what's going wrong?

Comment: I have edited the post!

Comment: SO is wrong place to search for file format documentation or library that would read it. If you have problem actually implementing particular part of reader - definitely would be good question.

Comment: A quick Google search yielded me [this](http://www.gtamodding.com/index.php?title=RPF_archive). It's a custom file type, not a zip. Reading the entry at the link may give you a good idea of what you need to do to read and modify the file.

Comment: You may open It with OpenIV application available online.